# Realm framework error with Strip: Stripping frameworks fatal error: lipo: -remove's specified would result in an empty fat file

Tags: ios, swift, realm, strip, lipo

I am having an ugly error since I've updated the Realm.framework.
The error is:

> Stripping frameworks
>   fatal error: lipo: -remove's specified would result in an empty fat file

If I select the box for "Run script only when installing" in build phase for the corresponding Run Script, it compiles for testing. However it does not when I try to archive.

Does anyone have a thought on this ? 
Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

This error could happen if you didn't follow the installation instructions listed at https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest#installation *exactly*.

The `strip-frameworks.sh` build phase is only necessary when using fat frameworks, such as the ones provided by Realm's zip downloads or Carthage with binaries. This error would happen if you're building Realm from source (e.g. with CocoaPods or `carthage update --no-use-binaries`), because it'll just build the architecture you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed the instructions very carefully, removed everything and repeated actions from scratch, and I always get the same issue. I have used CocoaPods or others. I imported the framework straight into my project...

Comment: could you compare your project's configuration with the equivalent installation example at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/installation to see how it's configured differently which could be causing this error?

Comment: At last, I just found how to solve the issue. I had an C++ library within my project, and deleting took away the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

An extra C++ library was causing the problem. Removing it solved it.